# Enabling CORS in Kubernetes API

Tags: cors, kubernetes

Is there a way I can enable CORS on Kubernetes API so that I can send ajax requests to Kubernetes API with a different domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by adding --cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"] argument to /etc/default/kube-apiserver file. Then restarted to kube-apiserver.

Comment: Where do you add it in this file?