# How to expose Kubernetes API with CORS enabled (Docker for Windows)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

For internal purpose, I'm building a dashboard application.
In this dashboard I need to display some info about Kubernetes (running pods, clusters, etc).

I'm trying to call my Kubernetes API from my web app (from browser).
Url of API is `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/`

I'm getting error on fetch data (CORS origin not allowed).

I've search on internet for hours trying to find solution but nothing is working.
I know there is other stack post giving some solution but I'm not sure how to apply it.
For ex. : [Enabling CORS in Kubernetes API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117640/enabling-cors-in-kubernetes-api)

Any of you know how to allow CORS origin on Kubernetes API (Docker for windows)?

Note: I'm using `kubectl proxy`

Comment: chrome does not allow CORS on localhost, you need to switch it off in the browser.

Comment: if you use Nginx to request your API you can simply configure Nginx for the allow-cross origin  API request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a server sided middle layer that can proxy your requests to api without needing CORS on the api itself.

For example, with nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://my-api-that-needs-cors;
  }
}
```

Take care to only expose what you need to expose.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you have any docs showing how to create this specific proxy with Nginx ? I'm not sore how to achieve it.

Comment: The magic is done in `proxy_pass` nginx directive, docs are here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
It will proxy all your requests to nginx to another server.
The `add_header` bit allows for cross domain requests from the browser. If you just have the snippet above as part of your nginx config that should be a good starting point.

Comment: Hey @frix-g, did the above solution work for you, did you have a chance to verify it in practice ?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit kubernetes API server yaml file, to get CORS working.

Add line **--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]** argument to **/etc/default/kube-apiserver** or **/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml** file, it depends where your kube-apiserver configuration file is located.

```
spec:
containers:
- command:
  - kube-apiserver
  - --cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]
```

Restart kube-apiserver.

Then add annotation to service configuration to `dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/"` in your service configuration file and apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, for anyone who comes to this problem and if you are using Minikube, maybe you could try: `minikube start --extra-config "apiserver.cors-allowed-origins=["http://\*"]"`.
For more information, please checkout [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4477).